# Force .net core website to promt for login and password

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

My company has developed an website using .net core 5 - This uses windows Auth and this works fine on PC where the users are logged in.

My problem is the site also is being used in mobile devices. Here the users are promted to login(no credentials found on the phone) - The problem the users have a need to change who is logged in on the site(more then one user per device)

To make the site promt for login/pass again i have used the following
First is just trigged by a menu click

```
    public IActionResult RedirectToLogin()
    {
      return RedirectToAction("Index", new { forceLogin = true });
    }
```

Here is use Return StatusCode(401) to get the site promt for login.
this code is working fine when running it from VS on a localhost - but when it is deployed the login promt never shows

```
   public IActionResult Index(string toastMessage = null, bool forceLogin = false)
    {
        if (forceLogin) //promt for login
        {
            string ip = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
            string cacheValue = $"logout_{ip}";
            if (_memoryCache.Get(cacheValue) == null)
            {
                _memoryCache.Set(cacheValue, string.Empty);
                return StatusCode(401);
                // return Unauthorized();
            }
            else
            {
                _memoryCache.Remove(cacheValue);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out why the "return Unauthorized();" dont trigger a login promt when deployed to a server. My best guess is the credentials are being cache somehow
The site is running on Windows server 2019 and IIS 10

Comment: Why not use the built in auth libraries?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/special-identities?force_isolation=true

Comment: @DanielA.White is there a buildin function that can do this ?